# increase maximum representable size for java heap space over 6GB on MAC

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

I'm working with an Model Checker on a Mac 10.6.8 64-Bit machine (32 GB Ram). My problem is that I can't reserve more than ~ 2 GB heap space.

I tried for example this :

```
./mymodelchecker -vmargs -d64 -Xms6g -Xmx6g
```

But I get this error-message :

```
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms6g The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
```

It seems to me that he heap space is working in a 32-Bit environment, but the machine is 64-Bit, Java is through -d64 is in 64-Bit mode and my Model Checker supports 64-Bit architecture.

How can I increase the maximum representable size of my heap space?

Comment: What does `java -version` report?  I bet it says that you are using a 32 bit JVM.

Comment: The `-d32` and `-d64` options only work on Solaris. On other platforms you have a JVM which is either 32-bit OR 64-bit and is not selectable.

Comment: $  java -version                                                   java version "1.6.0_33"
                                                                  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b03-424-10M3720)
                                                                    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03-424, mixed mode)

Comment: Can you paste the run jvm shell "mymodelchecker"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **modify** the `mymodelchecker` script, find the line that actually instantiates the java program and add `-Xms6g -Xmx6g` arguments.

Also, perhaps the model checker has a **configuration/property file** where you can set VM arguments without modifying the startup script.

Answer (score 0):

You can also checkout the top -p #processId to check if the stated heap is allocated to the process or not. look at the virtual memory allocated in the top report:

```
ps -aef | grep <your process identifier>
top -p <the process id of the process as returned by the previous statement>
```